# find the checkbox in table and check the checkbox on enter key press

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

how can i focus on the highlighted row checkbox and on enter key make the checkbox checked.
when i hit enter all the check box is checked but i want to check the checkbox of highlighted row.
[i want this highlighted row's checkbox to be checked on enter key press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHMP6.png)

```
<tbody id="navTable">
<tr class="lastRow" id="start">
  <td>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="selectedProduct" name="selectBox" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['pid']); ?>"></label>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Name']); ?><input type="text" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Name']); ?>" hidden="true"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="pPrice" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Price']); ?>" hidden="true"><?php echo $row['Product_Price']; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="pStack" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Stack_No']); ?>" hidden="true"><?php echo $row['Product_Stack_No']; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Purchased']); ?>" hidden="true"><?php echo ($row['Product_Purchased'] - $row['Product_Sold']); ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_GST_Rate']); ?>" hidden="true"><?php echo $row['Product_GST_Rate']."%"; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Purchase_Date']); ?>" hidden="true"><?php echo $row['Product_Purchase_Date']; ?></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($row['Product_Expiry_Date']); ?>" hidden="true"><?php echo $row['Product_Expiry_Date']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

```
window.displayBoxIndex = -1;
    var Navigate = function (diff) {
        displayBoxIndex += diff;
        var oBoxCollection = $("#navTable tr");
        if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length) {
            displayBoxIndex = 0;
        }
        if (displayBoxIndex < 0) {
            displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
        }
        var cssClass = "navBox";
        oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
    }
    $(document).on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            //alert("hello");
            $('.navBox').trigger('click');
            $("input:checkbox").click();
            return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            //down arrow
            Navigate(1);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            //up arrow
            Navigate(-1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean "highlighted row checkbox"?

Comment: Please explain full expected behavior in more detail. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: there is a modal in which there is a table and with this code i am able to navigate in between the rows by up and down key. but i want make the check the checkbox checked of the row which is highlighted with the enter key.